# Magento 2 frontend customization

Tags: magento2, frontend, development

I need some pointers to get started with customizing the frontend of a Magento 2 webshop. I know very litle about this stuff but since we might have a custommer that wants us to make a magento webshop they gave me the task to figure out how Magento works. I tried to do [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html) but that didn't do anything. If you have any good tips, tricks, guides or anything else useful please send it my way.

Answer (score 1):

Creat your new custom theme follow [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) instruction

From folder vendor find your parent theme and copy all file inside `web` folder.

Example: i copy from blank theme

[image: blank_theme]

Go to folder `lib\web\css`
copy all theses file to your css folder of your theme

> source\lib_responsive.less
> source\lib_lib.less
> components_modals.less

Clear cache and re-deploy static files

Answer (score 0):

I did a long write up on the basics of theming:

> https://www.customerparadigm.com/magento-2-theming-basics/

Here is another good one from Jamersan:

> https://jamersan.com/lets-get-started-theming-magento-2-part-1/

For books i really liked this one for front end work:

> https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/magento-2-theme-design-second-edition

Max's channel on youtube isn't comprehensive, but there is some great content here:

> https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxbWGz6h6KNQsi2ughRUV2Q

When you want to get into the area of module development, there is no better way to start then with Alan Storm's work:

> https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/

And I just finished this course, and it's a great counter point to Alan Storm's work on module development:

> https://www.udemy.com/mastering-magento-2/